# PowerShell - Find out Who has Read permissions on a Network Folder Share

Tags: powershell, network-share, file-permissions

In a Windows Server & Active Directory environment, where a particular network-share is shared with only certain AD users/groups.  Is there a way, using PowerShell, to find out who has read permissions to this share?  I tried to follow the instructions on [this post](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/11/26/use-powershell-to-find-out-who-has-permissions-to-a-share/), but receive an error, which is shown below after the code sample.

Here is the sample .ps1 code I used to try this:

```
$cred = Get-Credential -Credential mydomain\myself
$share = "MyTarget"
$cn = "FooBar"

$query = "Associators of {win32_LogicalShareSecuritySetting='$share'} 
    Where resultclass = win32_sid"

Get-WmiObject -query $query -cn $cn -cred $cred | 
    Select-Object -Property @{LABEL="User";EXPRESSION=
        {"{0}\{1}" -f $_.ReferencedDomainName, $_.AccountName}}, SID
```

Here is the error message:

```
Get-WmiObject : Not found 
At line:8 char:1
+ Get-WmiObject -query $query -cn $cn -cred $cred |
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

UPDATE: Per the comment below, I have found that the share I'm looking for is a **sub-folder** of an actual named share, 2 levels down.  Using this line of PowerShell to find that server's named shares:

```
Get-WmiObject -ComputerName "FooBar" -Class win32_LogicalShareSecuritySetting | select PATH
```

So for example:
Computer name is `FooBar`.  One of the many listed shares is `MainShare`.  Under that folder, we go `\SomeStuff\MyTarget`, and **MyTarget** is the folder I need to look at permissions for.  So the full path would be `\\FooBar\MainShare\SomeStuff\MyTarget`.

Comment: Are you sure the $share name is correct and you have the right credentials to access it? The code works for me. If i change $share to something that doesnt exist then I get the same error you got. If you run 
`Get-WmiObject -ComputerName <computername> -Class win32_LogicalShareSecuritySetting | select PATH` do you get a list of the share names back?

Comment: @MassNerder that's an excellent check -- I did that and found that the folder I'm looking for was NOT listed.  It's *under* a shared folder, so now I need to figure out how to... recurse?  Get child shares?  Let me add that to the question.  Thanks!

Comment: The share and the share permissions are set on MainShare. If you want share permissions on \\FooBar\MainShare\SomeStuff\MyTarget then you would have to create a new share point directly to that folder

Comment: Good info sir!  If you want to enter it as the official answer, I'd be happy to mark it as such.  Cheers!

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The share and the share permissions are set on MainShare. If you want share permissions on \FooBar\MainShare\SomeStuff\MyTarget then you would have to create a new share point directly to that folder